# Rock, Paper, Scissor - Trouble keeping score (browser console)

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an Odin Porject (Javascript Basic): Rock, Paper, Scissor only in the browser console and I'm having trouble keeping score. I'm still a beginner so excuse my messy code. I've tried adding another function to keep the score but it didn't work either.

```js
choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
let playerScore = 0
let computerScore = 0

function getComputerChoice() {
    return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
}

function getPlayerChoice() {
    let input = prompt('Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissor?')
    input = input.toLowerCase()
    return input
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors' || 
            playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock' || 
            playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        computerScore++
        return `You lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`
        
    } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors' || 
            playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock' || 
            playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        playerScore++
        return `You win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`
    } else
        return `It's a tie!`
    
}

function game() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        const playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();
        const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
    }

    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
        return 'You beat the computer! You are a genius'
    } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
        return `You got beat by the computer. Practice your throws!`
    } else {
        return `You tied with the computer!`
    }  
}

game();
```

Comment: This is javascript, nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Isn't the variable `playerScore` not keeping the score? "**Having trouble**" is not a valid description of the problem. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: This seems to work for me... what is wrong with it? It is kinda weird that it works, because you should use `&&` in your if clauses, as `&` is `bitwise AND`  and `&&` is `logical AND`

Comment: @Apollo79 The two operands are booleans, so a bitwise AND works too.

Comment: What is the problem here? I don't see any error or clear problem statement in the question. Just "it didn't work" is not enough information to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can greatly simplify the test to see who wins. There is a circular order: Rock < Paper < Scissors < Rock...

Therefore, you win if the index of the computer's choice in the choices array is exactly one less than the index of your choice in the choices array. To account for the fact that it must loop around, so that Rock beats Scissors, you can turn a -2 result of the subtraction into +1 by using the mod `%` operator.

```js
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
let playerScore = 0, computerScore = 0

function getComputerChoice() {
  return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
}

function getPlayerChoice() {
  let choice;
  while(true) {
    choice = prompt('Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors?').toLowerCase();
    if(choices.includes(choice)) return choice;
    else console.log('Invalid choice, please try again');
  }
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if(playerSelection===computerSelection) {
    return 'Draw'
  }
  else if((((choices.indexOf(playerSelection) - choices.indexOf(computerSelection)) + 3) % 3)===1) {
    playerScore++
    return `You win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`
  }
  else {
    computerScore++
    return `You lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`

  }
}

function game() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    const playerSelection = getPlayerChoice()
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice()
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
  }

  if (playerScore > computerScore) {
    return 'You beat the computer! You are a genius'
  } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
    return `You got beat by the computer. Practice your throws!`
  } else {
    return `You tied with the computer!`
  }
}

console.log(game())
```

Comment: This is a very neat trick using modulo to determine the winner in a cyclic manner. This answer does not address the issues the OP had with their code though - it simply provides an alternative. The OP's original issue was the improper use of the bitwise-AND operator instead of the logical-AND.

Comment: @h0r53 Yes, I agree, your answer actually answers the question as asked. I just had too much time on my hands :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using a single `&` as part of your conditional statements. This is not how you say "logical this AND that" in JavaScript. A single `&` is a bitwise AND which is very different from a logical AND (also known as a 'logical conjunction').

You should use two `&` characters within your conditional statements. Example:

```js
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors' || 
            playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock' || 
            playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        computerScore++
        return `You lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`
        
    } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors' || 
            playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock' || 
            playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        playerScore++
        return `You win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`
    } else if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
       return "Tie!"
    } else {
        return `Error: Invalid input\n${playerSelection}\n${computerSelection}`
    }

}
```

It's also worth noting that you had a logical error in your `if`/`else` structure. They way you have it, entering something that isn't within `'rock'`, `'paper'`, `'scissors'` would result in returning "You win..."

I've addressed that error in my example code above. Now if either user enters something invalid, neither players score is incremented and the game will print an error message.

Comment: The original nor your fixed example account for ties. I'm not sure of the requirements, though.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I am also unsure of the requirements. I simply addressed the issue the OP had related to inappropriate use of the bitwise-AND instead of the logical-AND operator. I also fixed the final `else` which was incorrectly returning "you-win" in the case of invalid input or ties. The final else in my example would say "Error" on ties, you are correct. I'll address that, though my intention was to show the OP their error and not write the entirety of the code for them.